# How to use SQLite in Redux async?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite, react-redux

Is possible to make an SQLite request async in Redux? The implementation from the documentation isn't async because `dispatch(onLoading(false))` is fired before all DB inserts.

**Action**

```js
const saveData = async () => {
    await dispatch(onLoading(true));
    await dispatch(saveSQL('DROP TABLE "bepr_problematiky"'));
    await dispatch(
        saveSQL(
            'CREATE TABLE "bepr_problematiky" ( "id" integer NOT NULL, "uid" integer DEFAULT NULL, "title" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "text" text NOT NULL, "file" varchar(255) NOT NULL );'
        )
    );

    for (const insert of inserts) {
        await dispatch(
            saveProblematiky(
                `INSERT INTO 'bepr_problematiky' VALUES(${insert.id}, ${insert.uid}, '${insert.title}', '${insert.text}', '${insert.file}');`
            )
        );
    }

    return await dispatch(onLoading(false));
};
```

**Component**

```
export const saveSQL = (sql: string) => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<ProblematikyInterface>) => {
        await db.transaction(async (tx) => {
            await tx.executeSql(sql, [], (tx, results) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'LOAD_PROBLEMATIKY',
                    payload: []
                });
                console.log('Saved');
            });
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: `dispatch` is synchronous; you likely want either an async middleware or some other multi-step async process solution--there are several.

Comment: I'm confused.. if you wanted it to be asynch, why not just remove your "await" prefix? Also, unless you're bulk loading SQL records, why would you want them to be asynch? Most sets of SQL operations imply order, so making them asynch would just let all hell break lose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQLite for react native, I would recommend this WatermelonDB https://nozbe.github.io/WatermelonDB/ as it is a library built on SQLite and has many other features.

As in for your questions - If I am not mistaken, you would like to have an await your insert db call inside a function so that you can manipulate the loading condition for your UI state right?

I believe you can use redux-thunk for this as it resolve the async actions for redux.  https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure#writing-async-logic-with-thunks (this example is using redux-toolkit)

I hope it helps. If you already have the answer for this, do share it out as well. Thanks . Cheers !!